# Getting textView values from listView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have a `listView` that gets filled by a `simpleCursorAdapter` from a `sqlite` database.
Every `listView` entry has 3 `textViews`  : Value,hour and date.

I filter the `listView cursor` by the date value so if i enter `24-07-2013` in the filter it will only show the entries from the sqlite database that have the date set to that.It will sometimes show 1 or 3 or any number,depending on how many entries are in the database.

What i want to do is to add all the `Values` into a total and show it in a separate `TextView` or something.

So my question is : how do i get the `Values` from the `listView` and add them up ?

Here's my code,i'll try not to copy it all.

```
private void displayListView() {

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            SQLiteT.DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3,
            SQLiteT.DB_COLUMN_2_NAME3,
            SQLiteT.DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3,

    };

    int[] to = new int[] {

    R.id.numeprod3,
    R.id.cantotala3, 
    R.id.ultimulpret3,

    };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_info3,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView13);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter3);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
```

And this is how i extract data from the database :

```
 public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
        mCursor = this.sqliteDBInstance3.query(DB_TABLE_NAME3, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3, DB_COLUMN_2_NAME3, DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3
                }, null, null, null, null, null);

    } else {
        mCursor = this.sqliteDBInstance3.query(true, DB_TABLE_NAME3,
                new String[] {KEY_ROWID, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3,
                        DB_COLUMN_2_NAME3, DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3 },
                DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3 + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {

    Cursor mCursor = this.sqliteDBInstance3.query(DB_TABLE_NAME3,
            new String[] {KEY_ROWID, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3, DB_COLUMN_2_NAME3,
                    DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3 }, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

UPDATE :

I ended up doing this.It isn't the nicest solution i think but it does the job.

```
//Added to this :
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            totaluri= dbHelper.getAllCountries(s.toString());
            //ore=dbHelper.getAllCountries2(s.toString());
            int pff=totaluri.length;
            float totalulma = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<pff;i++){totalulma=totalulma+Float.parseFloat(totaluri[i]);}
            totaltotaluri.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totalulma));

//And created this method inside my database activity 
public String[] getAllCountries(String inputText) {
    Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance3.query(DB_TABLE_NAME3,
            new String[] { DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3 }, DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3 + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3));
            i++;
        }
        return str;
    } else {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

So,when the input in the filter edittext gets changed,it runs another query in the database.If there's a better,more efficient way to do this please tell me...i really want to learn and of course,i don't want to make my app use too many resources.

Comment: Can you do it outside the adapter? Why not loop over the cursor after it returns from query?

Comment: Sure,guess i can.But how do i do that ? I'm a total noob with cursors,adapters and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment suggested, you could loop over the cursor after getting it from query, and this way your adapter doesn't have to do it.

```
public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
    Cursor mCursor = this.sqliteDBInstance3.query(DB_TABLE_NAME3,
            new String[] {KEY_ROWID, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME3, DB_COLUMN_2_NAME3,
                DB_COLUMN_3_NAME3 }, null, null, null, null,
        null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        updateSum(mCursor);
    }
    return mCursor;
}

private void updateSum(Cursor cursor) {
    int sum = 0;
    final int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
    for (cursor.moveToFirst; !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int value = cursor.getInt(index);
        sum += value;
    }
    // do something with sum
}
```

Comment: +1 solid answer. The other way to do it is with a custom adapter, which I tend to like anyway because it is easier to debug a custom adapter than one of the `Simple*Adapter` classes in my experience.

Comment: There are two separate activities,the second snippet of code i wrote is from my database activity.This code you gave me,goes in that database activity,right ? Then i would need to send it to the other activity. How can i do all this from the first activity ? It also needs to work for fetchCountryByName.Sorry for not giving enough details from the get go

Comment: Move the `updateSum()` method to your second activity and call it after `Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();` instead

Comment: Didn't see your last comment till now,sorry..I tried something,it's in my update.Could you please tell me if it's a good solution or not ? Had some trouble trying yours,gives me some errors

Comment: Your update involves querying for a cursor, pulling out values into a string array, then parsing them all into floats. Why not just loop over the cursor for the values directly? (with `cursor.getInt(...)` or `cursor.getFloat(...)`)